# How is order working in a Collection?

Tags: java, collections

This class is ordered by name but what does it happen when various objects have the same name?

```
public class MyStuff implements Comparable<MyStuff> {
    MyStuff(String n, int v){ name = n; value=v;}
    String name; int value;
    public int compareTo(MyStuff m){
        return name.compareTo(m.name);
    }
    public String toString() { return name + " " + value + " ";}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<MyStuff> l = new ArrayList<MyStuff>();
        MyStuff m0 = new MyStuff("hola",1);
        MyStuff m1 = new MyStuff("hola",1);
        MyStuff m2 = new MyStuff("hola",2);
        MyStuff m3 = new MyStuff("hola",2);
        l.add(m0);
        l.add(m1);
        l.add(m2);
        l.add(m3);
        Collections.sort(l);
        System.out.println(l);
        for(Object o: l) System.out.println(o.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[hola 1 , hola 1 , hola 2 , hola 2 ]
21722195
12719253
30758157
12773951
```

Which object is the first? Depends on value, hashcode..?

Comment: A `hash` is designed to produce a random number for data. In a hash collection this helps pseudo-randomly arrange the data so that only the key given is likely to be in the same bucket.  In short, a hash is designed to do the opposite of sorting. ;)

Answer (score 4):

As is specified in [java doc: Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)` is guaranteed to be stable.

By stable, it means: for objects that are equal, i.e. compare returns 0, the relative order is not changed, i.e. the one on the left prior to sorting is still on the left after the sorting.

By the way, as is specified in [java doc: Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28byte%5b%5d%29), `public static void sort(Object[] a)` is guaranteed to be stable as well. It seems like in `java.util` library, sort always guarantees stability when the elements are not primitives.

Answer (score 0):

No. **hashcode has nothing to do with it**. It is the order of elements you add to list.

`Collections.sort()` method uses `Arrays.sort()` for `ArrayList` which is a `mergesort` which only swaps elements if `compareTo returns >0`